# C Program to Convert a Text File into a CSV File

Tags: c, csv, text

The question is to convert a text file into a CSV file using C programming. The input text file is formatted as the following:

`JACK Maria Stephan Nora
20 34 45 28 
London NewYork Toronto Berlin`

The output CSV file should look like:

```
Jack,20,London
Maria,34,NewYork
Stephan,45,Toronto
Nora,28,Berlin
```

The following code is what I tried so far:

```
void  load_and_convert(const char* filename){
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char ch;

    fp1=fopen(filename,"r");
    fp2=fopen("output.csv","w");

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
         ch=fgetc(fp1);
         fprintf(fp2,"%c",ch);    
         if(ch==' '|| ch=='\n')
              fprintf(fp2,"%c,\n",ch);
}
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

}
```

The output from my code looks like:

```
Jack,
Maria,
Stephan,
Nora,
20,
34,
45,
28,
London,
NewYork,
Toronto,
Berlin,
```

How should I modify my code to make it work correctly?

What's the idea to treat this question?

Comment: Oh my... `fgetc` returns an *`int`* and you will know that you've read to the end of file by the fact that the return value is `EOF`.

Comment: Other than that you're not even *close* to the solution, since you need to *transpose* the output; either you need to read the contents into a 2D array or use 3 `FILE *`s or something equally convoluted.

Comment: If it *really* is this small, you can read the 3 lines with `fgets`; and use `strtok_r` to tokenize them separately...

Comment: Sometimes, a higher level language is the solution...

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp1=fopen(filename,"r");` and 
    `fp2=fopen("output.csv","w");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "my error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(fp2,"%c,\n",ch);`  This outputs a extra space or a extra newline.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest: `int fputs( "\n", fp2);`

Comment: The code needs to read all three lines, a separate buffer for each line. (suggest using `fgets()`) then process all three lines in parallel, one token at a time

Answer (score 0):

Since I have some times, here is a working solution for you (tried my best to make the solution as elegant as I can):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 50

typedef struct  
{  
  char name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
  int age;
  char city[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
} Person;

void getName(char *src, char *delim, Person *people) {
  char *ptr = strtok(src, delim);
  int i = 0;
  while(ptr != NULL)
  {
    strncpy(people[i].name, ptr, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    i++;
  }
}

void getAge(char *src, char *delim, Person *people) {
  char *ptr = strtok(src, delim);
  int i = 0;
  while(ptr != NULL)
  {
    people[i].age = atoi(ptr);
    i++;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }
}

void getCity(char *src, char *delim, Person *people) {
  char *ptr = strtok(src, delim);
  int i = 0;
  while(ptr != NULL)
  {
    strncpy(people[i].city, ptr, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
    i++;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  Person somebody[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE];
  FILE *fp;
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  int ln = 0;

  fp = fopen("./test.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
      return -1;

  // Read every line, support first line is name, second line is age...
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    // remote trailing newline character
    line = strtok(line, "\n");
    if (ln == 0) {
      getName(line, " ", somebody);
    } else if (ln == 1) {
      getAge(line, " ", somebody);
    } else {
      getCity(line, " ", somebody);
    }
    ln++;
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE; j++) {
      if (somebody[j].age == 0) 
        break;
      printf("%s, %d, %s\n", somebody[j].name, somebody[j].age, somebody[j].city);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  if (line)
      free(line);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are needing to do is non-trivial if you want to approach the problem holding all values in memory as you transform the 3-rows with 4-fields in each row, to a format of 4-rows with 3-fields per-row. So when you have your datafile containing:

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/col2csv3x4.txt
JACK Maria Stephan Nora
20 34 45 28
London NewYork Toronto Berlin
```

You want to read each of the three lines and then transpose the columns into rows for `.csv` output. Meaning you will then end up with 4-rows of 3-csv fields each, e.g.

**Expected Program Output**

```
$ ./bin/transpose2csv < dat/col2csv3x4.txt
JACK,20,London
Maria,34,NewYork
Stephan,45,Toronto
Nora,28,Berlin
```

There is nothing difficult in doing it, but it takes meticulous attention to handling the memory storage of object and allocating/reallocating to handle the transformation between 3-rows with 4-pieces of data to 4-rows with 3-pieces of data.

One approach is to read all original lines into a typical pointer-to-pointer to char setup. Then transform/transpose the columns into rows. Since conceivably there could be 100-rows with 500-fields next time, you will want to approach the transformation using indexes and counters to track your allocation and reallocation requirement to make your finished code able to handle transposing a generic number of lines and fields into fields-number of lines with as many vales per row as you had original lines.

You can design your code to provide the transformation in two basic functions. The first to read and store the lines `(say`getlines`) and the second to then transpose those lines into a new pointer-to-pointer to char so it can be output as *comma separated values*

One way to approach these two functions would be similar to the following that takes the filename to read as the first-arguments (or will read from `stdin` by default if no argument is given). The code isn't trivial, but it isn't difficult either. Just keep track of all your allocations, preserving a pointer to the beginning of each, so the memory may be freed when no longer needed, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTR 2
#define NWRD 128
#define MAXC 1024

/** getlines allocates all storage required to read all lines from file.
 *  the pointers are doubled each time reallocation is needed and then
 *  realloc'ed a final time to exactly size to the number of lines. all
 *  lines are stored with the exact memory required.
 */
char **getlines (size_t *n, FILE *fp)
{
    size_t nptr = NPTR;     /* tracks number of allocated pointers */
    char buf[MAXC];         /* tmp buffer sufficient to hold each line */
    char **lines = calloc (nptr, sizeof *lines);

    if (!lines) {   /* validate EVERY allocaiton */
        perror ("calloc-lines");
        return NULL;
    }

    *n = 0;         /* pointer tracks no. of lines read */
    rewind (fp);    /* clears stream error state if set */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line o finput */
        size_t len;

        if (*n == nptr) {   /* check/realloc ptrs if required */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * nptr * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-tmp");
                break;
            }
            lines = tmp;    /* assign new block, (opt, zero new mem below) */
            memset (lines + nptr, 0, nptr * sizeof *lines);
            nptr *= 2;      /* increment allocated pointer count */
        }

        buf[(len = strcspn(buf, "\r\n"))] = 0;  /* get line, remove '\n' */
        lines[*n] = malloc (len + 1);           /* allocate for line */
        if (!lines[*n]) {                       /* validate */
            perror ("malloc-lines[*n]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[(*n)++], buf, len + 1);   /* copy to line[*n] */
    }

    if (!*n) {          /* if no lines read */
        free (lines);   /* free pointers */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* optional final realloc to free unused pointers */
    void *tmp = realloc (lines, *n * sizeof *lines);
    if (!tmp) {
        perror ("final-realloc");
        return lines;
    }

    return (lines = tmp);   /* return ptr to exact no. of required ptrs */
}

/** free all pointers and n alocated arrays */
void freep2p (void *p2p, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free (((char **)p2p)[i]);
    free (p2p);
}

/** transpose a file of n rows and a varying number of fields to an
 *  allocated pointer-to-pointer t0 char structure with a fields number 
 *  of rows and n csv values per row.
 */
char **transpose2csv (size_t *n, FILE *fp)
{
    char **l = NULL, **t = NULL;
    size_t  csvl = 0,       /* csv line count */
            ncsv = 0,       /* number of csv lines allocated */
            nchr = MAXC,    /* initial chars alloc for csv line */
            *offset,        /* array tracking read offsets in lines */
            *used;          /* array tracking write offset to csv lines */

    if (!(l = getlines (n, fp))) {  /* read all lines to l */
        fputs ("error: getlines failed.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    ncsv = *n;
#ifdef DEBUG
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        puts (l[i]);
#endif

    if (!(t = malloc (ncsv * sizeof *t))) { /* alloc ncsv ptrs for csv */
        perror ("malloc-t");
        freep2p (l, *n);        /* free everything else on failure */
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ncsv; i++)   /* alloc MAXC chars to csv ptrs */
        if (!(t[i] = malloc (nchr * sizeof *t[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-t[i]");
            while (i--)         /* free everything else on failure */
                free (t[i]);
            free (t);
            freep2p (l, *n);
            return NULL;
        }

    if (!(offset = calloc (*n, sizeof *offset))) {  /* alloc offsets array */
        perror ("calloc-offsets");
        free (t);
        freep2p (l, *n);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!(used = calloc (ncsv, sizeof *used))) {    /* alloc used array */
        perror ("calloc-used");
        free (t);
        free (offset);
        freep2p (l, *n);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually transposing cols to csv rows */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < *n; i++) { /* read next word from each line */
            char word[NWRD];    /* tmp buffer for word */
            int off;            /* number of characters consumed in read */
            if (sscanf (l[i] + offset[i], "%s%n", word, &off) != 1)
                goto readdone;  /* break nested loops on read failure */
            size_t len = strlen (word);         /* get word length */
            offset[i] += off;                   /* increment read offset */
            if (csvl == ncsv) { /* check/realloc new csv row as required */
                size_t newsz = ncsv + 1;    /* allocate +1 row over *n */
                void *tmp = realloc (t, newsz * sizeof *t); /* realloc ptrs */
                if (!tmp) {
                    perror ("realloc-t");
                    freep2p (t, ncsv);
                    goto readdone;
                }
                t = tmp;
                t[ncsv] = NULL;     /* set new pointer NULL */

                /* allocate nchr chars to new pointer */
                if (!(t[ncsv] = malloc (nchr * sizeof *t[ncsv]))) {
                    perror ("malloc-t[i]");
                    while (ncsv--)   /* free everything else on failure */
                        free (t[ncsv]);
                    goto readdone;
                }

                tmp = realloc (used, newsz * sizeof *used); /* realloc used */
                if (!tmp) {
                    perror ("realloc-used");
                    freep2p (t, ncsv);
                    goto readdone;
                }
                used = tmp;
                used[ncsv] = 0;

                ncsv++;
            }
            if (nchr - used[csvl] - 2 < len) {  /* check word fits in line */
                /* realloc t[i] if required (left for you) */
                fputs ("realloc t[i] required.\n", stderr);
            }
            /* write word to csv line at end */
            sprintf (t[csvl] + used[csvl], used[csvl] ? ",%s" : "%s", word);
            t[csvl][used[csvl] ? used[csvl] + len + 1 : len] = 0;
            used[csvl] += used[csvl] ? len + 1 : len;
        }
        csvl++;
    }
    readdone:;

    freep2p (l, *n);
    free (offset);
    free (used);

    *n = csvl;

    return t;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **t;
    size_t n = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(t = transpose2csv (&n, fp))) {
        fputs ("error: transpose2csv failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (t[i])
        puts (t[i]);

    freep2p (t, n);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/transpose2csv < dat/col2csv3x4.txt
JACK,20,London
Maria,34,NewYork
Stephan,45,Toronto
Nora,28,Berlin
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/transpose2csv < dat/col2csv3x4.txt
==18604== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18604== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18604== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18604== Command: ./bin/transpose2csv
==18604==
JACK,20,London
Maria,34,NewYork
Stephan,45,Toronto
Nora,28,Berlin
==18604==
==18604== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18604==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18604==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 4,371 bytes allocated
==18604==
==18604== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18604==
==18604== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18604== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.